# How to retrieve the data from multiple table relation in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am working in a project in php Laravel 5.5. I have tables tbl_borrower, tbl_property_owner, tbl_property, tbl_property_borrower. The structure of the table is like this.
[image: tbl_property_owner has one or many properties and property are assigned to the borrower in tbl_property_borrower. The borrower can also have many properties.]
In report I have to show the borrower details, property owner details, property details which are assigned. the report should be like this.
[image: In report, there should be borrower details and property details and assigned property details are shown on the basis of tbl_property_borrower]
I have tried making one to many relationship in model like this.

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property','property_owner_id');
}

public function assigned_property()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PropertyBorrower','property_id');
}
```

Like this, i can retrieve property details of property owner but i cannot
get the values which are assigned to the borrower according to the property owner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your relation mapping is wrong.

Comment: how can i improve my relation?\

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
use App\Property;
use App\PropertyBorrower;

public function properties()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class, 'property_owner_id', 'id');
}


public function assigned_property()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyBorrower::class, 'property_id', 'id');
}
```

In your Borrower Model

```
public function borrower()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PropertyBorrower::class, 'id', 'borrower_id');
}
```

Comment: I
 cannot get the values which are assigned to the borrower according to the property owner.

Comment: i will modify the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios in relationship.
   1. Based on the correct naming conversion just giving model name.

```
 Example :
         consider you have users table and you have another table like comments table. 
             Users Table fields = id, name
             Comments Table     = id, comments, user_id.
```

Here you followed the correct naming conversion like user_id so you only need to give model name like below,

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Comment'); or return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)
```

2. Different foreign key name .

   Example :

   consider you have users table and you have another table like comments table.

> ```
>   Users Table fields = id, name
>      Comments Table     = id, comments, author_id.
> ```

Here the foreign key different compare to table name so you have to tell the key in relationship function.

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Comment', 'author_id', 'id');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: how this is related to my question?